# Value Objects member used to validate another value object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
    public sealed class UKCurrency : ICurrency
    {
        private static readonly int _decimalPlaces=2; 
            private static readonly decimal[] _denominations = new decimal[] {
                50.00M, 20.00M, 10.00M,
                5.00M,  2.00M,  1.00M,
                0.50M,  0.20M,  0.10M,
                0.05M,  0.02M,  0.01M,
            };

            public IEnumerable<decimal> Denominations
            {
                get { foreach (var denomination in _denominations) yield return denomination; }
            }
    }

    public sealed class DenominationCounter
    {
        private readonly decimal _cost;

        public decimal Cost
        {
            get { return _cost; }
        }

        public ICurrency Currency
        {
            get { return _currency; }
        }

            public DenominationCounter(decimal cost, ICurrency currency)
            {
                if (currency == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Currency cannot be null", "ICurrency");
                if (cost < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Cost cannot be negative", "Cost");
                if (decimal.Round(cost, currency.DecimalPlaces) != cost)
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Concat("Cost has too many decimal places.  It should only have: ", currency.DecimalPlaces), "Cost");
                _cost = cost;
                _currency = currency;
            }

public IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<decimal, int>> CalculateDenominations()
        {
            var target = _cost;
            foreach (var denomination in _currency.AvailableDenominations)
            {
                var numberRequired = target / denomination;
                if (numberRequired >= 1)
                {
                    int quantity = (int)Math.Floor(numberRequired);
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(denomination, quantity);
                    target = target - (quantity * denomination);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The DenominationCounter constructor throws an exception if the cost has the wrong number of decimal places.

Notice that the UKCurrency class is used to validate the DenominationCounter as shown below:

```
if (decimal.Round(cost, currency.DecimalPlaces) != cost)
```

Is this a normal to approach validation like this:

1) A Value Objects member is used to validate an entity

2) A Value Objects member is used to validate another value object

I am asking this because I have never seen validation approached like this before and I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment these days.

Comment: I'd still put the same answer. not sure I understand your question

Comment: for a start neither of your objects is a struct

Comment: @Ewan, I am using objects because of this: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/12/04/net-value-type-ddd-value-object/

Comment: @Ewan, I am asking if it is normal for the Currency class to be used in the validation of the DenominationCounter class i.e. is it normal to do: if (decimal.Round(cost, currency.DecimalPlaces) != cost)

Comment: @Ewan, DenominationCounter is an immutable object so I believe I should not be assigning in a method as per your other answer.

Comment: in the current example, you are persumably missing a DenomCounter.GetCurrency(cost) so it would still be immutable

Comment: @Ewan, could you post your answer again so I can review it again? Thanks.

Comment: last time I was immediately downvoted twice. so im obviously missing something that at least 2 other people get

Comment: @Ewan, I have added the missing Getters.

Comment: no, I mean your DenominationCounter doesnt do anything, presumably you want to store the cost as a combination of currency denominations. in which case you could implement that as a method

Comment: Like @Ewan, I'm now confused as to what you are asking. `DenominationCounter`'s name and content seem completely at odds with each other. In what way does that type count anything? Also, I really dislike your `UKCurrency : ICurrency` solution. You are creating a disjointed (ie, weakly cohesive) solution using polymorphism for no good reason.

Comment: I think I disagree with the enitre approach. use structs for value types, have an array of struct { int count, string denomination}  ie { 10, "5p" } if you need to record the exact money used. dont throw in constructors, except for negative count, which you are allowed because its antithetical to the type

Comment: @David Arno, I have added more code, which I hope helps to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Ewan, see comment above.

Comment: I have created a new answer that explains why I think your whole approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need for your `DenominationCounter` object. It's purpose is to provide an `IEnumerable<(decimal, int)>` (I've simplified your data type to use a tuple) via `CalculateDenominations`.

But that method is completely deterministic in nature. You are achieving nothing useful (beyond arguments around primitive obsession) by having instances.

Further, you are creating a non-cohesive solution to denominations by having multiple classes responsible for handling what should be a single responsibility. Don't just use subtype polymorphism just for the sake of it.

I'd make the whole lot a single static class, to maximise cohesion, to remove all the complications around constructors, to remove the need to duplicate functionality in every implementation of `ICurrency.Denomination` etc:

```
public enum Currency { GBP, EUR, USD, ... }

public static class Denominations
{
    private static readonly decimal[] GBPDenominations = new decimal[]
    {
        50.00M, 20.00M, 10.00M,
        5.00M,  2.00M,  1.00M,
        0.50M,  0.20M,  0.10M,
        0.05M,  0.02M,  0.01M,
    };

    private static readonly decimal[] EURDenominations = ...

    private static Dictionary<Currency, decimal[]> CurrencyDenominations =
        new Dictionary<Currency, decimal[]>
        {
            [Currency.GBP] = GBPDenominations,
            [Currency.EUR] = EURDenominations,
            ...
        };


    public static IEnumerable<(decimal denomination, int quantity)>
        CalculateDenominations(Currency currency, decimal cost)
    {
        var remainingCost = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in CurrencyDenominations[currency])
        {
            var numberRequired = remainingCost / denomination;
            if (numberRequired >= 1)
            {
                var quantity = (int)Math.Floor(numberRequired);
                yield return (denomination, quantity);
                remainingCost = remainingCost - (quantity * denomination);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explsin what you mean by: "But that method is completely deterministic in nature.".  Is your code a Domain Service? I thought domain services were none deterministic?

Comment: I honestly do not know what a domain service is. `CalculateDenominations` only uses constant values and its parameters to produce a result. It has no side effects (it doesn't access or modify external state). Therefore every time you call eg `CalculateDenominations(Currency.EUR, 34.77M)`, you will get the same response, for the lifetime of the application. Therefore `CalculateDenominations` is deterministic.

Comment: last question - when you say "it doesn't access or modify external state" I assume you mean instance variables?  Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily. External state could be instance or static variables, both within the class and in other classes. But it also covers other methods that access such state, as well as things external to the application (file systems, environment state, eg OS type, databases and so forth).

Comment: Can I ask where the validation is?

Comment: @w0051977, what is it that you feel needs validating?

Comment: cost.  Please see the DenominationCounter constructor in my post.

Comment: @w0051977, To be honest, I don't see the act of throwing exceptions for trivial things like that as validation; it's the programming equivalent of a toddler's temper tantrum. It's an irrational response. If you pass in a negative number into my code, you get an empty enumeration back. Give it £23.9765 and it'll ignore the `0.0065`. Both seem completely valid responses to me. If you disagree though, put your exceptions into `CalculateDenominations`. Throwing an exception from a static method is definitely no worse than throwing one in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have two different value objects. You have a value object and a fancy array. You probably need to combine a lot of UKCurrency and DenominationCounter. It's not wrong for a value object to validate that its dependencies are valid even if they are other value objects, but both objects need to be valuable independent of each other.

A value object needs a value that's actually comparable (even if you never do or never implement a comparison), UKCurrency doesn't have that. Every instance of UKCurrency is exactly the same, and even worse if CanadianCurreny existed it would be functionally identical to UKCurrency.

Try stating what your objects do/ what value they provide in 1-2 sentences. If you can't do that or what you said doesn't seem useful then something needs to change.

Comment: would you describe the code in my question as a domain service?

Answer (score 1):

OK So! here is my understanding of your approach

1. In your domain you have a special value type eg. Currency In Denominations
2. You want to prevent the construction of a value type that would be impossible by definition, ie half a 10p piece.
3. You are modeling value types as immutable reference types. rather than using value types. Because of reasons.
4. Some of the information required to validate the 'value type' is contained in another class. eg the possible denominations of a particular currency.

Bad things:

1. Throwing in constructors is generally bad. The exception to the rule is impossible value types eg 31st of Feb
2. All of your examples could be refactored to do the validation in a method rather than a constructor.

If you are married to your way of doing things, then you have no alternative to your current solution. Yes it seems slightly odd, but it is functional.

If you want a solution where you don't have that particular combination of validation, why not get rid of the constructor exceptions completely?

```
public class ImmutableListOfCoins 
{
    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, uint>> listOfCoins {get; private set;}
    public ImmutableListOfCoins(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, uint>> listOfCoins) 
    {
         ....
    }
}

public static ImmutableListOfCoins CalculateDenominations(decimal cost)
    {
        var target = _cost;
        if (decimal.Round(cost, currency.DecimalPlaces) != cost)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cost has too many decimal places.");
        }
        var loc = new Dictionary<decimal,uint>();

        foreach (var denomination in _currency.AvailableDenominations)
        {
            var numberRequired = target / denomination;
            if (numberRequired >= 1)
            {
                var quantity = (uint)Math.Floor(numberRequired);
                loc.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal, uint>(denomination, quantity));
                target = target - (quantity * denomination);
            }
        }
        return new ImmutableListOfCoins(loc);
    }
```

Comment: Would this class exist in the core of the application.  From what I can see it is neither an entity nor a value object?

Comment: no, list of coins is your value object. you have a service or factory class to create them from other inputs which may be invalid

Comment: So the list of coins value object would be contained in the core.  Where would your CalculateDenominations object be contained - in a domain service in the core?

Comment: depends on the rest of your model I guess. in your example its pretty hard to think of an alternate bit of logic. but If we go back to the player.fitness you can imagine you might want to create games where the validation critiera change or are different. perhaps for the olympics you can only create teams where the fitness level of players is 10x the min requirement

Comment: or more likely, they are all born in a specific country

Comment: Instead of putting the validation logic in: CalculateDenominations; I guess I could put it in: CanCalculateDenominations and then call CanCalculateDenominations from CalculateDenominations.  I believe this is a Domain Service.

Comment: naming is getting a bit crazy but yeah

Comment: why is the naming crazy? I believe I am following the guidance here: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/SnackMachines/SnackMachine.cs.  How would you name it?

Comment: ChangeCalculator

Comment: It is not calculating change.  It is calculating denominations to meet a cost.

Comment: EwansAmazingCostCalcService

Comment: Ha +1.  I meant would you name the validation routine: CanDoSomething.

Comment: prob not. maybe IsValid but its not important

Comment: Thanks.  One more thing - can I ask why you omitted checking for negative values in the validation.  Just wandered if there was a reason.

Comment: uint cant be negative

Comment: One more thing before I accept - is this a Domain Service in the DDD world?

Comment: it depends where you put it in relation to your domains. you could have it buried in CashMachine.Vend() or in a separate domain CurrencyService_UK.DivideAmountIntoNotes()

Comment: If it was a separate domain with this class only, then would it be a Domain Service?  Sorry to be pedantic - I just want to make sure I get my terminology right.

Comment: Strictly speaking a Domain Service is a way to talk between Domains. If you just have a floating static function without a domain. I'm not sure what the correct terminology is.

Comment: OK, I see.  Could you confirm that it would exist in the core though rather than the infrastructure.

Comment: really that is up to you and your domain.

Comment: With regards to your comment: "it depends where you put it in relation to your domains. you could have it buried in CashMachine.Vend() or in a separate domain CurrencyService_UK.DivideAmountIntoNotes()".  If this class (and interface) was in an assembly on its own then would you describe it as a domain service? Sorry to be pedantic about terminology - I am just trying to get the concept of a domain service clear in my head. +1